# Python: Human time to epoch timestamp

Tags: python, date, datetime, timestamp

Hi there curently I am trying to convert human readable date to unix timestamp like this

```
import time
print(time.mktime(time.strptime("18:00","%H:%M")))
```

the problem is that time.strtime doesn't take today's date into consideration so it creates a tuple with 1990 as year, 01 month, 01 day which of course then feeded to time.mktime produces wrong timestamp

and I can't just modify datetuple like DateTuple.tm_mday before feeding it into time.mktime as tuples are read-only

so how can I imput time in human readable form like 10:00 and date has to be inputed automaticly

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: Are you looking for `datetime.combine(datetime.today(), datetime.strptime("18:00","%H:%M").time()).timestamp()`? You'll need to `from datetime import datetime` for that. Note that Python will assume the time you supply is local time, unless you provide a time zone. The resulting UNIX time will refer to UTC seconds since the epoch.

Comment: yep, thats the one :)
Thanks